# Base de dados Tabela com produtos (problema com o tamanho do produto)

Tags: modelo-relacional, tabela-banco-de-dados

Bom dia antes de tudo, imaginemos que a minha tabela produtos teria os campos (**codigo_produto**, nome, genero, preco , tamanho), ao ter o campo tamanho nesta tabela envolveria com que ao ter o codproduto1 repetido n vezes quantos tamanhos eu tivesse, como devo contornar isto, estáva na duvida se estaria correto criar nova tabela com (cod_produto, tamanho) como chave composta... obrigado.

Comment: ou então, tenho a 2FN mal feita e o campo tamanho não é dependente do código produto, e devo fazer deles os 2 chave composta ?hmmm não tenho experiência,  não tenho a mínima ideia da saída correta deste problema..whelp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens de criar uma nova tabela:

**tbl_tamanhos**
cod_tamanho (PK) - *chave primaria* 

codigo_produto (FK) - *chave estrangeira*
tamanho_produto

A relação entre elas será de N:N.

Comment: mas, estando dessa maneira, tendo 2 produtos com o mesmo tamanho nessa relação, teria de ficar N:N não? pois  N tamanhos = 1 produtos, ou 1 Tamanhos = N produtos, exemplo tamanho47 = produto1,produto2. estou certo ou apenas estou a abordar de maneira errada ?

Comment: Sim tens razão, não me lembrei desse pormenor. A relação será de N:N. De qualquer das maneiras tens que ter sempre a tabela dos tamanhos, tal como mencionei na resposta anterior.